# How to add custom footer to a specific page?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, footer, arabtex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlestyle=hang,twoside]{elegantbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?
\usepackage{attachfile}% to embedd audio file
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}    % <---
\usepackage{longtable}



%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}


% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter \, #1\,}{}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[\style]{\bfseries}
     {\filcenter\LARGE\enspace\bfseries{\color{structurecolor}%
       \IfAppendix{\appendixname}{\chaptername~\thechapter}\enspace}}
     {1pt}{\bfseries\color{structurecolor}\LARGE\filcenter}

%End--------------------------------------------

%--------------------------------------------------
%Arabic  Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{arabxetex}

%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
 
\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

%End--------------------------------------------


%% new:

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip,font=Large]{caption}

%==================

%==================


\begin{document}

Requird custom footer for specific pages.


\vfill
\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=blue,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইখফা & 

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইখফা মীম সাকিন &

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=yellow,fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ক্বলক্বলা &

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=cyan,fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ক্বলব & 

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=blue,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইদগাম & 

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=green,fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইদগাম মীম সাকিন & 

 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=magenta,fill=magenta] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! গুন্নাহ
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

But I would like to get :

[image]
Here is the [complete file.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/qziey375bbog7xu/elegantbook.zip/file)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot run your code because I don't have the fonts, but you could use the `fancyhdr` package and then put your coloured footer in with `\fancyfoot[C]{...your code...}`

Like

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{...your code...}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Or if you want it only on a specific page, use `\thispagestyle{fancy}`

**NOTE:** If you put the code into `\fancyfoot`, make sure there are no empty lines in it.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=blue,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইখফা & 
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইখফা মীম সাকিন &
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=yellow,fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ক্বলক্বলা &
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=cyan,fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ক্বলব & 
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=blue,fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইদগাম & 
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=green,fill=green] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! ইদগাম মীম সাকিন & 
%
 \begin{tabular}{c}
\tikz\draw[color=magenta,fill=magenta] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{tabular}\! গুন্নাহ
\end{tabular}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: @ PietervanOostrum It is not working for tabular.

Comment: You must make sure that there are no empty lines between the tabulars (or anywhere else in the argument). See the NOTE that I added.